# Could not change the address pointed by char * c

Tags: c, char, mbedtls

I am receiving a buffer inside this function , I would like to ignore the first character by incrementing the buffer address by one.

I increment the buffer but out side the function the buffer contains the received data but it's not incremented.

It's strange !! could any one help me please !!

```
int mbedtls_net_recv_timeout( void *ctx, unsigned char *buf, size_t len,
                  uint32_t timeout )
{
int ret,recv;
struct timeval tv;
fd_set read_fds;
int fd = ((mbedtls_net_context *) ctx)->fd;

if( fd < 0 )
    return( MBEDTLS_ERR_NET_INVALID_CONTEXT );

FD_ZERO( &read_fds );
FD_SET( fd, &read_fds );

tv.tv_sec  = timeout / 1000;
tv.tv_usec = ( timeout % 1000 ) * 1000;

ret = select( fd + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, timeout == 0 ? NULL : &tv );

/* Zero fds ready means we timed out */
if( ret == 0 )
    return( MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_TIMEOUT );

if( ret < 0 )
{
#if ( defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN32_WCE) ) && !defined(EFIX64) && \
!defined(EFI32)
    if( WSAGetLastError() == WSAEINTR )
        return( MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_WANT_READ );
#else
    if( errno == EINTR )
        return( MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_WANT_READ );
#endif

    return( MBEDTLS_ERR_NET_RECV_FAILED );
}

/* This call will not block */
recv = mbedtls_net_recv( ctx, buf, len );
buf = buf + 1;
printf("Receiving\n");

return( recv );
}
```

Comment: The arguments in `c` are passed by *value*. You can't change them from within a function.

Answer (score 1):

Like Eugene Sh said, arguments in C are passed by value.

Example :

```
void Test(int value)
{
  value++;
}

...

int foo = 3;
Test(foo);
// here, foo is still 3
```

If you want to pass `foo` by reference in C, you need to pass it's pointer

```
void Test(int* value)
{
  *value++;
  value++;
}

...

int foo = 3;
int *fooPtr = &foo;
Test(fooPtr);
// Now, foo is 4, but fooPtr still is &foo.
```

Note that I also incremented the pointer inside the `Test()` function, but since the pointer itself is passed by value, it's not incremented outside the `Test()` function.

In order to achieve what you want, you need to pass the pointer by reference (as a pointer) :

```
void Test(int** value)
{
  **value++;
  *value++;
}

...

int foo = 3;
int *fooPtr = &foo;
Test(&fooPtr);
// Now, foo is 4, and fooPtr was incremented.
// This is just an example ; don't use fooPtr beyond this point, its value is wrong.
```

You need to pass your buf pointer as a reference to be able to change the pointer value :

```
int mbedtls_net_recv_timeout( void *ctx, unsigned char **buf, size_t len,
                  uint32_t timeout )
{

  [... snip ...]

  /* This call will not block */
  recv = mbedtls_net_recv( ctx, *buf, len );
  *buf = *buf + 1;
  printf("Receiving\n");

  return( recv );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should increment the pointer buf before passing it to the function 'mbedtls_net_recv' like this,

```
/* This call will not block */
    buf = buf + 1;
    recv = mbedtls_net_recv( ctx, buf, len );
    printf("Receiving\n");
    return( recv );
```